# How to watch for a value which depends on another value vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, computed-properties

First off, sorry for the vague title; I couldn't come up with a really succinct one. Here's my situation:

Let's say I have users, topics and comments in a vuex store. Users have names, a list of topics as well as the topic they have currently selected:

```
users: {
  1: { 
      name: 'Tom',
      topics: [1, 2],
      selectedTopic: null // set to 1 and then 2 when user clicks "next"
    },
  2: {... }
},
topics:
  1: { 
      title: 'Post!',
      comments: [1, 2],
      selectedComment: null
    },
  2: { ... }
},
comments:
  1: { 
      title: 'Cool!'
    },
  2: { ... }
}
```

If a user is selected, I want to show their name. If a user also selects a topic, this topic should be displayed as well; they can also cycle through the topics. For every topic, they can cycle through the comments in the same way. Thus:

```
computed: {
  // some getters
  // ...
  user () {
    return this.getUser(this.userId)
  },
  topic () {
    return this.getTopic(this.user.topics[this.user.selectedTopic])
  },
  comment () {
    return this.getComment(this.topic.comments(this.topic.selectedComment])
  }
```

In this case, the cycling works, but the console shows a *TypeError: "this.user.topics is undefined"* or *"this.user.selectedTopicis undefined"* at the start (only sometimes), which is true, of course, since we haven't selected a user yet. On the other hand, if I replace this with

```
  topic () {
    if (this.user) return this.getTopic(this.user.topics[this.user.selectedTopic])
  }
```

I don't get any errors, but neither does the value update when the selected topic is changed. Is there a good way to handle the issue?

Comment: You can use safeguards - `return this.getTopic(((this.user || {}).topics || {})[(this.user || {}).selectedTopic || ''])`

Comment: @IVOGELOV Thanks – but this doesn't help, I still get ```(intermediate value).topics is undefined```...

Comment: should `topic()` `computed` be: `topic () { if (this.user) return this.getTopic(this.user.selectedTopic) }` ?

Comment: When you expect some value to be `undefined` or `null` - you should append `|| default` so that the expression will evaluate to the given default value (you will choose this default depending on the situation - e.g. it could be an empty array or empty object or 0 or empty string ....). You should provide a default for any value you expect to be `undefined` sometimes.

Comment: @CatoMinor I'm afraid not :( user.selectedTopic is the array index for user.topics, which is not the same as the topic ID, since the IDs are adopted from an external source and are not numerical...

Comment: @IVOGELOV I first had trouble finding the right place to put the default value, but in the end, a simple ```return this.getTopic((this.user.topics || {})[this.user.selectedTopic])``` turned out to be enough. Thank you!

Comment: Your version is actually a slightly simplified/stripped version of my first response :) Glad to see you understood the idea!

Comment: Yes, it was based on your first comment. If you want to submit that as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62048580/how-to-watch-for-a-value-which-depends-on-another-value-vue?noredirect=1#comment109742762_62048580) by [Ivo Gelov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5962802/ivo-gelov), I arrived at

`return this.getTopic((this.user.topics || {})[this.user.selectedTopic])`

This seems to do the trick.